# Capturing the "Copy To" event in Outlook 2010

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I'm writing an add-in for Outlook 2010 (C#) that acts when messages are dragged to a PST file.  I'm using

```
    olExplorer.BeforeItemCopy += new Outlook.ExplorerEvents_10_BeforeItemCopyEventHandler(olExplorer_BeforeItemCopy);
    olExplorer.BeforeItemCut += new Outlook.ExplorerEvents_10_BeforeItemCutEventHandler(olExplorer_BeforeItemCut);
    olExplorer.BeforeItemPaste += new Outlook.ExplorerEvents_10_BeforeItemPasteEventHandler(olExplorer_BeforeItemPaste);
```

to capture the events, but have noticed that I can circumvent these functions when I use the "Copy To" or "Move To"  options.

How do I go about capturing the other two events?

**UPDATE:**

I've managed to capture "Move To", but "Copy To" is baffling me

Comment: I've started working with Redemption, but that appears to be making it more complex.  Redemption is great in that it captures the CopyTo event, but it's per item, and I only want to prompt the user once if they are copying, e.g., 100 mail messages from their inbox to a PST

Comment: It is your resposibility to delay the processing - you can use a timer that gets reset every time an event fires. When no event fires for the predefined time interval (2-3 sec?), you can process the accumulated notifications.

Comment: Thanks, Dimitry.  I responded on the other board as well, but do you have any samples of a wrapper-based timer that I can use?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. The BeforeItemCopy event fires before an item is copied to the Clipboard, for example: when you press [Ctrl + C] or from context menu.